# Summing solutions of a set of equations

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, transcendental-equations

Consider a set of transcendental equations for $x \in (0,1):$

$$ f_i^s(x)=i^{\frac{s}{\log_i(x_i)}}=x_i, $$

for $i=1,2,3,\cdot \cdot \cdot$

Summing the solutions yields:

$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty x_i=\zeta(\sqrt{s})= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\sqrt{s}}}.$$

What's wrong with this argument? Is summing solutions together useful outside of differential equations, where the general solutions can be found by adding solutions together via the superposition principal?

Is there a set of equations that when solved and solutions added together yield $\zeta(s)?$

Edit:

$$f_i^{s^2}(x)=i^{\frac{s^2}{\log_i(x_i)}}=x_i.$$

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty x_i=\zeta(s).$$

Comment: What's the argument? Or what do you suspect is incorrect about the steps?

Comment: I thought maybe it wasn't logical to sum the solutions up

Comment: I mean if your aim was the sum up the solutions, then it would seem logical :) Is $2^{+\sqrt{s}}$, $3^{+\sqrt{s}}$, $\ldots$, also solutions to equations $2,3,\ldots$?

Comment: Yeah for $x>1$ those are the solutions